# Bizarre Internet Connectivity Issue - Possibly DNS Related

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I'm working with a fresh install of Ubuntu, and I'm having a strange issue that I believe is DNS-related, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. In a nutshell, I am connecting to the network, but I cannot pull down any websites.

I will say right up front though, that all of my other devices-including a VirtualBox Instance of Ubuntu created with the same iso file I used to install to the problem pc-are connecting and going out to the internet just fine. Also, changing the settings in the network ui's "edit connection" has no effect.

Here's the gist of the issue. If I ping an IP, 8.8.8.8 for instance, eveything looks ok. However, if I ping or use the host command on a host name, then it fails.

I tried changing the resolv.conf, even though I know the change will be overwritten upon a restart, just to see if it would change the behavior and it did.

But, the ping results did not change, nor can my browser get out to the internet.

I've tried just about every solution I can find on the interwebs, to no avail. I'm really beating my head against a wall here, so any help is appreciated.

This website is telling me I'm not allowed to embed images in my questions yet, so here are some links to screen shots of terminal while completing the actions listed above:

[the first series of pings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHGfJ.png)

[after editing resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWAkV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, I found a solution to this problem. Or more accurately, I found an article written by someone who experienced this same issue with Ubuntu 17.04 and thankfully had more knowledge than myself.

This gist of it is that it is indeed a DNS issue. The problem is being caused by a service called "systemd-resolved." More specifically, the DNSSEC function of the service is not playing well with resolv.conf. The fix is to either disable that feature (not secure) or replace it with another service called "unbound." In my case, I followed the author's steps to disable DNSSEC, and it fixed the problem immediately. That sufficiently proved to me that it was the issue; so, I then followed his steps to replace systemd-resolved with unbound. I can now browse the internet with abandon.

Here is a link to the [article](https://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/). If anyone would like to chime in with some in-depth technical explanation, I would enjoy it. Otherwise, thanks for tuning in.

Comment: You can accept your answer by clicking on the check mark available next to the answer(below the voting buttons).

Comment: Thanks for the top. I tried to check it, and it said I can accept my own answer in 9 minutes. I guess you have to wait 24 hours to accept your own answer.

Comment: The article link is not functioning. IF your post the correct, I greet you.

Comment: Sorry about that, the link should be working now