# Ubuntu 16.04 Cannot Resolve Hostname

Tags: dns, openstack, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I am trying to get my OpenStack instance of Ubuntu 16.04 able to resolve DNS. I just created the instance from the given default Ubuntu image and I am trying to `apt-get update` my machine. However, I am getting the following error messages:

```
ubuntu@udia-rac:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have the following dns.cfg file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/98-google-dns.cfg
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This generates my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
ubuntu@udia-rac:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

When trying to ping google.com, the host is unresolved, but pinging the IP directly seems to work.

```
ubuntu@udia-rac:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
ubuntu@udia-rac:~$ ping 216.58.216.206
PING 216.58.216.206 (216.58.216.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.216.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=55.5 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.216.206: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=55.5 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.216.206: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=55.5 ms
^C
--- 216.58.216.206 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 55.532/55.557/55.582/0.193 ms
```

I've tried restarting my resolvconf service `sudo service resolvconf restart`, but that did not fix my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some resolveconf issue. Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/948508/bizarre-internet-connectivity-issue-possibly-dns-related

Comment: @Redbob I looked at that answer, unfortunately the link to the said magical article is broken. I will look more into unbound